# Getting CoinMarketCap API to work with Ruby on Rails 2020?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, blockchain

Before coinmarketcap made their API into tiered free/payed you could get it working with

```
    class Currency < ApplicationRecord 
            def current_price`
               url = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
                request = HTTParty.get(url + self.slug)
              response = JSON.parse(request.body)
      end

    end
```

But now it requires an API key which you can get on the basic free tier but I'm at a loss as to where to implement the API key in the above code?
Like I know i need a get and to include the API key but they only mention how to do that with Python C#

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#section/Authentication) clearly state that:

> You can supply your API Key in REST API calls in one of two ways:
>
> - Preferred method: Via a custom header named `X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY`
> - Convenience method: Via a query string parameter named `CMC_PRO_API_KEY`

With HTTParty providing headers is trivial:

```
url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/'
request = HTTParty.get(url + self.slug, 
  headers: { "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY" => Rails.application.credentials.coinmarketcap[:pro_api_key] }
)
```

But you really should avoid doing HTTP calls from your model as it already has way to many responsibilities. Create a separate class instead that touches the application boundary:

```
class CoinMarketCapClient
  include HTTParty
  format :json
  base_uri "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com"
  attr_reader :api_key  

  def intialize(api_key:)
    @api_key = api_key
  end

  def ticker(slug, **opts)
    self.class.get("/ticker/#{slug}", headers: {
      "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY" => api_key
    })
  end
end
```